# json - Getting user IP address - NonFree

Tags: json, ip, clientip

I have a question. I have a website that is visited by 3000000 visitors per day. I have to detect their IP address and make a decision for them.

I do not want to use my own application. I just want to call a cloud platform to identify this.

E.g.: http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=getip

A good example, but I am looking for a professional service, which I am happy to pay for. Can you recommend anything?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get client's IP address using javascript only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-using-javascript-only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at mashape.com. I think it's the best place to find the WebService you want.

I found this one : IP-UTILS https://www.mashape.com/mark-sutuer/ip-utils

And this one : WhatIsMyIp
https://www.mashape.com/theproxisright/whatismyip

Anyway, there is many solutions : https://www.mashape.com/explore?query=get%20IP%20address